# Access Key of Map Created Component

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to access the `key` of a map created component like the one below...

```
data.map((data, index) => 
  <li 
    key={ index }
    onClick={ handleClick }
  >{ data }</li>
)
```

...or is a `data` attribute required to store and access the `index` like in the example below

```
data.map((data, index) => 
  <li 
    key={ index }
    data-index={ index }
    onClick={ handleClick }
  >{ data }</li>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `key` prop is only used by React for render optimization purposes. It cannot be seen in the DOM. So if you want to be able to access the index from inside `handleClick`, you'll need to get the value into the DOM somehow - like with your `data-index`.

For this particular situation, another option could be to pass it into `handleClick`, eg:

```
data.map((data, index) => 
  <li 
    key={ index }
    onClick={ e => handleClick(e, index) }
  >{ data }</li>
)
```